# Copy string into an array in Assembly

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, copy

I am attempting to copy a string into an array in the Assembly language. Basically the program asks a user for their name, then adds them to a list of users. I can read in the string just fine, but am unsure how to store string values into an array. I know the eax value stores the length of the string, but I need to store the string itself. Any tips on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: x86 assembly? which syntax: AT&T or Intel?

Answer (score 2):

To store the strings in an "array" you store the addresses of the start of the strings.

Comment: How can you store the addresses at the start of the strings in x86 assembly?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you mean like this :

```
.model small
.code
org 100h

data:
    kal1 db 'MIKROSKIL$'
    kal2 db 11 dup(?)
code1:
    mov bx,0
ulang1:
    mov dl,kal1[bx]
    mov kal2[bx],dl
    inc bx
    cmp dl,'$'
    jne ulang1
    mov ah,9
    mov dx,offset kal2
    int 21h
    int 20h
end data
```

Comment: Which type of assembly language is this?

Comment: This is a 16-bit x86 DOS `.com` program, MASM or TASM syntax.